# Control data access on the storage server (locally and remotely)

Tags: centos, storage

My current employer would like me to have some sort of system in place where the access to the data is being logged, this including the sysadmin. Currently we have one server that runs a CENTOS on it and the files are accessible to the users via samba shares.

My question, is there a software that can log whatever changes have been made to the files stored on the NAS via samba but also if the data is accessed locally by the sysadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `auditd` to provide a complete log of everything that gets accessed.  Unfortunately, anyone with administrative access to the server could disable that logging (or manipulate the logs after the fact) to hide any malfeasance.

Comment: Looked into auditd but as you said is easy to manipulate/delete the logs.

Comment: The only way to separate out this stuff is with massively over-complicated siloisation.  Tell your current employer to get over themselves.